# Add custom attribute to contact form itself (wordpress plugin)

Tags: wordpress, contact-form

Contact form uses shortcode to embed forms on pages like this : [contact-form-7 id="105" title="My title"]

I would like to add a custom attribute to the form itself but don't know how to achieve this. I'd like to have a result like this one :

```
<form id="formId" myCustomAttributeHere>
...
</form>
```

Any help would be nice

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? I am looking for the same with wp-forms. I am deploying static wordpress website via netlify and requires an attrib for forms to work in netlify.

Comment: no sorry I didn't

Comment: I ended up replacing the form with its html code using dev tools (copy and paste) and adding attributes to the html code. It works!

Answer (score 0):

It might be a solution to use the `do_shortcode_tag` like:

```
function contact_form_filter( $output, $tag, $atts, $m ) {
  if ($tag === 'contact-form-7' && $atts['title'] === 'Whatever') {
    // manipulate $output
  }

  return $output;

}
add_filter('do_shortcode_tag', 'contact_form_filter', 10, 4);
```

Read more https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/do_shortcode_tag/.